# How can I get the Value of date from an input using event listeners?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm having a hard time figuring out on how can I console the dates in my date-pickers using an event, So for example I clicked the `from date`, it should console and get the text in the datepicker, same as to my `to date`. Anyway to solve this? I can't find a solution for this, please I need help, it's my deadline today

```js
var chartData1 = [];

generateChartData();

function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 500);
  firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

    var a1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;
    var b1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 + i)) + 500 + i * 2;
    chartData1.push({
      "date": newDate,
      "value": a1,
      "volume": b1
    });
  }
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "extendToFullPeriod": false,

  "dataSets": [{
      "title": "first data set",
      "fieldMappings": [{
        "fromField": "value",
        "toField": "value"
      }, {
        "fromField": "volume",
        "toField": "volume"
      }],
      "dataProvider": chartData1,
      "categoryField": "date"
    }],

  "panels": [{

      "showCategoryAxis": false,
      "title": "Value",
      "percentHeight": 70,

      "stockGraphs": [{
        "id": "g1",

        "valueField": "value",
        "comparable": true,
        "compareField": "value",
        "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
        "compareGraphBalloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>"
      }],

      "stockLegend": {
        "periodValueTextComparing": "[[percents.value.close]]%",
        "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]"
      }
    },

    {
      "title": "Volume",
      "percentHeight": 30,
      "stockGraphs": [{
        "valueField": "volume",
        "type": "column",
        "showBalloon": false,
        "fillAlphas": 1
      }],

      "stockLegend": {
        "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]"
      }
    }
  ],

  "chartScrollbarSettings": {
    "graph": "g1"
  },

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
    fullWidth: true,
    cursorAlpha: 0.1
  },

  "periodSelector": {
    "position": "left",
  },

  "dataSetSelector": {
    "position": "left"
  }
});

chart.addListener('rendered', function(event) {
  var dataProvider = chart.dataSets[0].dataProvider;
  $(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField").datepicker({
    "dateFormat": "dd-mm-yy",
    "minDate": dataProvider[0].date,
    "maxDate": dataProvider[dataProvider.length - 1].date,
    "onClose": function() {
      $(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField").trigger('blur');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery stuff -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- amCharts -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Datepicker has a [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event:

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the
>   selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this
>   refers to the associated input field.

**Demo**:

```js
var chartData1 = [];

generateChartData();

function generateChartData() {
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 500);
  firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

    var a1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;
    var b1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 + i)) + 500 + i * 2;
    chartData1.push({
      "date": newDate,
      "value": a1,
      "volume": b1
    });
  }
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "stock",
  "extendToFullPeriod": false,

  "dataSets": [{
      "title": "first data set",
      "fieldMappings": [{
        "fromField": "value",
        "toField": "value"
      }, {
        "fromField": "volume",
        "toField": "volume"
      }],
      "dataProvider": chartData1,
      "categoryField": "date"
    }],

  "panels": [{

      "showCategoryAxis": false,
      "title": "Value",
      "percentHeight": 70,

      "stockGraphs": [{
        "id": "g1",

        "valueField": "value",
        "comparable": true,
        "compareField": "value",
        "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
        "compareGraphBalloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>"
      }],

      "stockLegend": {
        "periodValueTextComparing": "[[percents.value.close]]%",
        "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]"
      }
    },

    {
      "title": "Volume",
      "percentHeight": 30,
      "stockGraphs": [{
        "valueField": "volume",
        "type": "column",
        "showBalloon": false,
        "fillAlphas": 1
      }],

      "stockLegend": {
        "periodValueTextRegular": "[[value.close]]"
      }
    }
  ],

  "chartScrollbarSettings": {
    "graph": "g1"
  },

  "chartCursorSettings": {
    "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
    fullWidth: true,
    cursorAlpha: 0.1
  },

  "periodSelector": {
    "position": "left",
  },

  "dataSetSelector": {
    "position": "left"
  }
});

chart.addListener('rendered', function(event) {
  var dataProvider = chart.dataSets[0].dataProvider;
  $(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField").datepicker({
    "dateFormat": "dd-mm-yy",
    "minDate": dataProvider[0].date,
    "maxDate": dataProvider[dataProvider.length - 1].date,
    "onClose": function() {
      $(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField").trigger('blur');
    },
    "onSelect": function(dateText) {
      console.log('date:', dateText);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery stuff -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- amCharts -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amstock.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: can i set them in seperate var?

Comment: like date1 and date2?

Comment: no i mean startdate =13-12-2017 then endDate =19-12-2018 like this

Comment: you want set them as initial value ?

Comment: like if i select first date picker set var date1 then select 2nd datepicker to var date2

Comment: @JeremyAdriandeVera `this` inside the callback function refers to the input field the datepicker instance was attached to, so if you have any id or specific class set on each input field, you can determine which one the event fired for this way.

Comment: you can use [setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate): `$( ".amcharts-start-date-input" ).datepicker( "setDate", "13-02-2017" );` and `$( ".amcharts-end-date-input" ).datepicker( "setDate", "19-12-2018" );`

Comment: bro pls help me, i need to vars

Comment: edit your question and add an exemple of the expected result you want to achieve